# Laravel firstOrCreate without Eloquent

Tags: laravel

Eloquent has a `firstOrCreate` method which gets a model based on a condition, or creates it if it doesn't exist.

Is there any equivalent method in Laravel's query builder (i.e. NOT in Eloquent)? For example:

`$row = DB::table('users')->where('user_id', 5)->firstOrCreate('name' => 'Peter', 'last_name' => 'Pan');`

That would try to get a row from `users` with `'user_id'==5`. If it doesn't exist, it would insert a row with that id number, plus the other mentioned fields.

EDIT: I'm not trying to apply my question with users. I used users as an example to make as clear as possible what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why you don't want to use Eloquent ?

Comment: I don't think so - you can check the builder source: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html but you're unlikely to find it.

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan The example is a bit unfortunate, as users are quite appropriate for Eloquent. I'm actually trying to make a simple system for which I think it would be overkill to create a model in Eloquent.

Comment: @Racso a user model comes with Laravel.  Seems pointless not to make use of it here.  It's also very easy to create a model, Eloquent requires next to no configuration if you follow the conventions.

Answer (score 3):

`updateOrInsert` function with empty values  give me the result like `firstOrCreate`

Comment: Perfect for me where I am updating multiple Laravel apps with the same DB structures where the names and amounts of DBs is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, Laravel firstOrCreate is function, that says next:

```
public function firstOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    if (! is_null($instance = $this->where($attributes)->first())) {
        return $instance;
    }

    return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes + $values), function ($instance) {
        $instance->save();
    });
}
```

But you can add it with query micro:

```
DB::query()->macro('firstOrCreate', function (array $attributes, array $values = [])  
{
   if ($record = $this->first()) {
      // return model instance
   }

   // create model instance
});
```

So than you will be able to call it same way you do with Eloquent.

```
$record= DB::table('records')->where('alias', $alias)->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score -3):

Yeah of course! Just use normal SQL and  `->selectRaw( your conditions )` and look for if there is a entry where your specifications are.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: How is a raw select comparable to firstOrCreate?

Comment: @Devon Because you can execute normal queries with raw? He said he wanted a non-eloquent way of doing

Comment: the  is about firstOrCreate equivalent function not raw query